# Can't get youtube video urls using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm a noob to python and web-scraping.
I am trying to get a list of URLs of videos that come up as search results. I tried this:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

search_term = "python"
page = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_term)

soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

vids = soup.findAll('a',attrs={'id':'thumbnail'})

url_list = []
for v in vids:
    tmp = 'https://www.youtube.com' + v['href']
    url_list.append(tmp)
print(url_list)
print(vids)
```

But the output is just

```
[]
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?
If I do `print(soup)`, it prints out the whole webpage.
I want the `url_list` array to be filled with URLs like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefgh123` or similar

Comment: Have you tried to use User-Agent in the headers of your request?

Comment: have you looked at the data inside `page` ? if you try running a simple href finder with regular expressions you will find that there are no hrefs to videos in the returned page, thats because youtube uses javascript to load the data afterwards but you dont get that with the `requests` module - you need something like selenium to run a full browser for the results to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to find anything using beautiful soup, as its a javascript rendered website, try using selenium with chrome web driver or any other, which creates a browser instance, the video tags which you are trying to select using bs4 will be visible when the all the js code will be executed using selenium.

You can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options=Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#path to chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
url='link to video listings'
driver.get(url)
listings=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("your xpath expression")
for l in listings:
     print(l.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can't request will be blocked. Secondly youtube renders their page using js so you won't able to find the elements using bs4.

Consider something like selenium when scraping js heavy pages.

Comment: Yea actually I've messed around with Selenium a few months ago and I'm more comfortable with that. But I have to do nearly 100 searches. So I thought bs4 would be faster

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webbrowser module instead. Its a built in module and works fine...

here's code:

```
import webbrowser
user_input = "your input"
webbrowser.open(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={user_input}")
```

It works fine.

Comment: hey can you enumerate how to get the links I want from `webbrowser`??